# Change current directory for child process started with execve()

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables

I want to change the environment variable of a child process with `execve()` so that if the child process opens a file in the current directory it gets linked to another directory. What environment variable do I have to change to accomplish this task? `$PWD` is not working.

For example:

```
char *args[] = { .... };
char *env[] = { "PWD=/home/anydirectory_I_Wish", NULL };
execve( mycode, args, env);
```

Comment: You can use `chdir()` to change the current working directory

Comment: *PWD* is just an environment variable, only a command can change the current directory

Comment: Where is the child process?  `execve` will not create a new process, and unless there is a `fork` that you're not showing, then there is no child.

Comment: sorry I meant "be taken by another process"

Answer (score 5):

There is no environment variable that will accomplish this.

A relative pathname like `foo` or `bar/foo` passed to a system call such as `open(2)` is **always** resolved with respect to the *current working directory* (cwd).  The cwd is an attribute of the process and can only be changed with the system calls `chdir` or `fchdir` (and maybe some other obscure ways I am missing).   But neither `PWD` nor any other environment variable is used in resolving relative pathnames.

The idea of setting the environment variable `PWD` equal to the name of the cwd is a feature of shells, to make it convenient for scripts to access it.  Other programs do not necessarily need to handle `PWD` in any special way, or to update it when the cwd changes.  In particular, the OS makes no guarantee that `PWD` will be set to the name of the cwd within any arbitrary program.